# Conditional query with PDO prepare and bind statement

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo, bind, prepare

I am converting all my queries from mysql to PDO, and in this process I found a conditional query like a follows

```
if (isset($parameters['searchTerm'])) {
    $where =" And title LIKE '%{$parameters['searchTerm'] }%'";
} 

$sql = "Select * from table data Where tableId = 5 {$where} ";
```

and when I am trying to convert this query in PDO the expected syntax is as follows

```
if (isset($parameters['searchTerm'])) {
    $where =" And title LIKE :searchTerm";
} 



$sql = $dbh->prepare("Select * from table data Where tableId = 5 {$where}");



if (isset($parameters['searchTerm'])) {
    $sql ->bindParam(':searchTerm', '%{$parameters['searchTerm'] }%');
} 

$sql ->execute();
```

Now as you can See that the if condition `if (isset ($parameters ['searchTerm'] )) {...}` is repeated twice.

The reason is

1. I can not prepare the sql query before $where is being set thus $sql variable is initialized after first if statement
2. I can not bind the parameters until I prepare the sql so it has to be placed after the $sql is being prepared

So there is one if statement before `$sql = $dbh->prepare("Select * from table data Where tableId = 5 {$where}");` and one if statement after.

**And my question is:** Is there a way to remove this redundant if statement or I have to do it this way only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a handy PDO's feature that allows you to send array with parameters straight into execute()

```
$where  = '';
$params = array();
if (isset($parameters['searchTerm'])) {
    $where = " And title LIKE :searchTerm";
    $params['searchTerm'] = "%$parameters[searchTerm]%";
}
$sql = "Select * from table data Where tableId = 5 $where";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)
$stmt->execute($params);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: regarding php syntax I must have messed up with something while editing the queries so no worries for that.